# Is it possible to add records into Ms Access Form, while some fields are locked?

Tags: ms-access, edit, custom-fields, records

In my Ms Access form - I have a few locked fields.
So, that users won't be able to change existing information.
But they might still needed to add a new records into the Form.

Is it possible to be able to add a new records, without changing or removing an existing ones?

Thanks, as always!

Comment: What do you mean by "locked fields", is this a sub-form of some kind, text boxes, other?

Comment: Adding records using a form does not affect existing records. What is your question, exactly?

Comment: @Jiggles32 By "locked fields" I mean the "Text Box" type field - ClientName, for example - where I set a settings (under Data section) Enabled = no, Locked=yes. 
After the above setting , my form is no longer allows to add a new records

Comment: You'll need to write some VBA code that checks whether a record is a new record. If so, enable the form fields.

Comment: @MihaiAdrian
In my case it affects existing records.

After I changed settings in the existing records (see my comment above), I am not able to add a new records into my Form.
After I set my textbox field setting to Enabled=no, Locked=yes - after I press "new record" button - my ClientName "locked" field remains locked and doesn't let me enter a new record

My question - what settings do I have to set in order to be able to add a new record(s) into my Form, but after adding - the certain records should be not editable.
Is it possible?

thx!

Comment: Assuming you're referring to a form that was created from a Table Record Source, if every field is locked how would a new record be created? From what data would this creation take place? If you're simply trying to make certain relationships uneditable, make those ones locked, and leave the others unlocked. You can't create something from nothing, so to speak.

Comment: @Jiggles32
Yes, my form has been created from a Table Record Source.

" if every field is locked how would a new record be created?"
I thought so too - 

But, was just wondering - may be it's still somehow possible to make every new record "unlocked" or "editable". And then - after the info had entered - it should stay locked.
I think, Rene just explained a possible way of doing it...

Comment: When a control (Textbox, combobox) is locked then you can not type or edit any text in those control. So, when you create a new record then you need just unlock the control. So, create a button to `Add New` write codes to unlock the control where you need to type text. What `Rene` shows that will also do so but it will dim the control as it will be disabled. But lock unlock will only allow, disallow editing text while it do not din the controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an On Current event on form level.
Like

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

If Me.NewRecord Then
Me.txtField1.Enabled = True
Me.txtField2.Enabled = True

Else
Me.txtField1.Enabled = False
Me.txtField2.Enabled = False

End If

End Sub
```

Replace txtField1 and txtField2 with the names of your form fields.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to add new records and keep some form fields locked, you have to set the *Locked property* on the data tab only for those fields. You can do that in design mode, or you can do it via VBA code on form load.

See https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=180359 for examples.

Answer (score 1):

Your last comment explains things a little better, I believe what you're after is possible (assuming I have the right idea). There are many ways to go about doing what you suggest, but without more specifics it becomes harder to guide you. That being said, terminology you're looking for in this question is something along the lines of "Lock fields when the Current Record is not a New Record".

This may partially solve your problem, you can probably figure it out from there:

Within the form itself, go to the `Property Sheet` and Select `Data`. Within the `Data Tab` change `Allow Edits` to `No`.

This will allow only New Records to be added to your table through your form, which appears to be your end-goal.

(Of course, you'll need to remove any locks on the text boxes that still remain to add any new records)